# Is there a one liner in JavaScript or Lodash for includes() with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, lodash

In my program I'm often validating objects. That validation often includes checking if an object has all defined keys. Is there a one liner (short way, preferably single function call) to check that using pure JavaScript or Lodash (which I'm also using)?

So far I do it like in the code below. I'm looking for a more concise way.

```
function validator(object) {
  let requiredKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
  for (let requiredKey of requiredKeys) {
    if (!object.hasOwnProperty(requiredKey)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

validator({ key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3 });  // returns true
validator({ key1: 1, key2: 2 });           // returns false
```

NOTE 1: I can operate both on `object` or `object.keys()`, so the one-liner function can take `Object` as well as `Array`.

NOTE 2: There is `includes()` method on `Array`, but it takes only single argument. I'm looking for a version that would take multiple ones.

Comment: do you have some example object, to test with?

Comment: @NinaScholz I can provide you many example objects, but I don't really see the purpose of it. The code example show how it should work. I'm looking for an equivalent code, just shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and `thisArg` for the object.

```js
function check(object) {
    return ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'].every({}.hasOwnProperty, object);
}

console.log(check({}));
console.log(check({ key1: 1 }));
console.log(check({ key1: 1, key2: 2 }));
console.log(check({ key1: 1, key3: 3 }));
console.log(check({ key1: 0, key2: 0, key3: 0 }));
```

Without `thisArg`

```js
function check(object) {
    return ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'].every({}.hasOwnProperty.bind(object));
}

console.log(check({}));
console.log(check({ key1: 1 }));
console.log(check({ key1: 1, key2: 2 }));
console.log(check({ key1: 1, key3: 3 }));
console.log(check({ key1: 0, key2: 0, key3: 0 }));
```

Comment: Couldn't `.every({}.hasOwnProperty, object)` be written as `.every(object.hasOwnProperty)`?

Comment: it returns the error: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty: 'this' is null or undefined`

Comment: Oh. Still a nice idea and what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get it into a one-liner I used the arrow function to loop through object keys:

```js
function validator(obj){
  var arr=Object.keys(obj);
  let requiredKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
  return requiredKeys.filter(x => 
arr.includes(x)).length==requiredKeys.length;  
}
var t1 = validator({ key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3 });  // returns true
var t2 = validator({ key1: 1, key2: 2 });           // returns false
console.log(t1,t2);
```